# ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction - Jasper reporting

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, database-connection, connection-string, jaspersoft-studio

I'm facing this annoying problem in Jasper. I have created a report based on a PostgreSQL function. When I watch the preview, I do not have any problem with the results. However, when I publish the report and try to execute it, I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
```

I've checked on the internet for a possible solution, so far this is the only thing that I have found with a similar problem:

> https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/814793/report-execution-fails-due-read-only-transaction-mode

However, adding the property to the URL does not work, or I'm not so sure if I have to write it in this way:

`jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/data_base?defaultReadOnly="false"`

In Jasper, what else can I do? I only can query the function, and requiring any change in it is an HUGE bureaucratic issue.

Jasper Studio 6.3.0

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? You should also post the small *jrxml*

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) the JDBC connection parameter would be `readOnly=false`.

Have you verified that you are not connecting to a streaming replication standby server?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create JNDI base connection and try out.

```
<tomcat>/webapps/jasperserver/META-INF/context.xml
<tomcat>/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml
```